# Grid View View state

Tags: asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I'm Using a GridView in my Application.
My GridView has a checkbox column and when the checkbox is clicked, the page is redirected to an other form.

When I return to previous from, nothing comes and GridView data is lost.
I used session and it's working fine, but I want that checkbox which was clicked to also maintain there state.

Is there better method to do this?

Comment: I lost you @ "while return to previous from"..Can you pls elaborate?

Comment: which language? C# or vb? could you show some code?

Comment: iam using c# ..  and this is iam using to add datatable in session   dt = (DataTable)Session["ModifyUser"]; but i want to have checkbox checked when i return to previous page..

Answer (score 1):

Upon redirection to the next page, Iterate your Gridview to update your Datatable with a checked checkbox column and then set that datatable to a session variable. I am assuming that you are already storing your source Datatable to a session.

Sorry, but no other magic work around !!!

Comment: hi,yes iam maintaining session session dt = (DataTable)Session["ModifyUser"];  but how to keep state of checkbox. ok i got u , u mean to say i have iterate whole datatable again.. u get which col is checked.

Comment: you have to iterate all the grid rows and merge/update source datatable column and then put that datatable in session.

Comment: hey i understood but when i checking datable row n cols iam not getting any col for checkbox.. can u suggest me any good tutorial..